# Is there an function or query for live update to other calculated column values in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I have created a MySQL table in my server for my Packaging Business.

I have written a python script that sends all the data to the table using MySQL Connector and using the terminal to run my script I input the order details.

For example,
I want to create an order of a carton of size 15 x 15 x 15 (Inches [L x W x H]), and there are calculated columns of paper length

Paper length= (2 * (L + W)) + 2

However, if I do a typing error while putting the value in the terminal like 16 x 15 x 15...
I don't want to waste that entry as there is an auto-incremented column as well, but if you look closely the paper length value changes from 62 to 64 inches...

Is there any way to create a script running in the background forever that I edit the entry of (L) back to 15 from 16 as mentioned above, the paper length column of that row gets recalculated actively when I apply changes?

I use Beekeeper Studio to edit and view my entries. I tried the update function of the MySQL query but dint solve my purpose or maybe I did it wrong.

If you can help please let me know!?
Thanks in advance.

Below is the picture *sheet_size* is the paper length calculated column

[MySQL table sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHwiw.png)

Comment: Why do you want to store the values of calculated columns? You can SELECT them. Nevertheless, you could use a BEFORE UPDATE trigger.

Comment: *and there are calculated columns of paper length* Do you mean that this is generated column? if so then simply edit errorneous column value, and generated column value will be changed accordingly and automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, the columns are already pre-structured when I created the table, using CREATE TABLE query. You can view in the picture.

Comment: Just store the values needed to calculate and move the calculation to a mysql view. Then it's only calculated when you select on the view instead of hard coded in your table.